# how to correct a mistake made in the levels of a factor variable?

Tags: r, variables, factors, levels

let's say I have this dataframe

```
d = data.frame(x = c("1","1 2", "1 3", "2 3", "3", "4"))
d
```

and it has the variable x as a factor

```
d$x = as.factor(d$x)
```

However I discover an error in three of the levels that I wrote.

So I want to replace the values of these variables and their levels as follows :

I want to replace 1 2 with 1

I want to replace 1 3 with 1

I want to replace 2 3 with 2

```
levels(d$x)
```

so I want to correct it. when using the following method :

```
d$x[which(d$x == "1 2")] <- "1"
d$x[which(d$x == "1 3")] <- "1"
d$x[which(d$x == "2 3")] <- "2"
```

It create levels as follows

```
1 1 1 2 3 4
```

What I wish is the levels as follows

```
1 2 3 4
```

What should I do to handle this problem ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fct_collapse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
d %>% 
  mutate(x = fct_collapse(x, 
                          "1" = c("1", "1 2", "1 3"),
                          "2" = c("2", "2 3")))
  x
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 4
```

Comment: please note that I updated the question so it reflects more the problem I am facing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check edit with `fct_collapse`

Comment: Thanks a lot. the problem is solved as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is turning back to character while modifying:

```
d$x <- as.character(d$x)
d$x <- factor(sub(" .+", "", d$x))

d$x
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 4
# Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You split the text by the space and then you unnest the lists to long format. This will work if there are many issues. This also assumes that there is a space that defines the error as per your example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <-  data.frame(x = c("1","2", "3 4", "5", "6"))

d |>
  mutate(x = str_split(x, pattern = "\\s")) |>
  unnest_longer(x)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   x    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 1    
#> 2 2    
#> 3 3    
#> 4 4    
#> 5 5    
#> 6 6
```

Edit based on comments:
Here are two methods. One with `tidyverse` and one using base R.

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
d <-  data.frame(x = c("1","2", "3 4", "5", "6"))

d |>
  mutate(x = str_remove(x, "\\s4$")) 
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 5
#> 5 6

d$x[which(d$x == "3 4")] <- "3"
d
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 5
#> 5 6
```

Another edit based on more info:

```r
d = data.frame(x = c("1","1 2", "1 3", "2 3", "3", "4"))

d$x <- as.factor(gsub("(\\d+)\\s\\d+$", "\\1", d$x))

d
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 1
#> 3 1
#> 4 2
#> 5 3
#> 6 4

levels(d$x)
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: no it's not what I want. because the dataframe includes 5 subjects. and the 3 4 level is an error. and I must correct it into 3. I hope you see the problem now because I am dealing with an excel file that has this issue.

Comment: I dont think I am following. You want the string to stay as "3 4" but you want the factor level to read "3"? or you want to replace "3 4" with "3"?

Comment: replace 3 4 with 3

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Thanks. you managed to solve a bit of the problem but it's still not as I want because the dataframe I included does not explain my problem. will update the question so it reflects more the problem

Comment: Updated again. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dedicated function `recode()` in `dplyr` for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)

## initial factor
x <- factor(c("1","1 2", "1 3", "2 3", "3", "4"))
levels(x)
#> [1] "1"   "1 2" "1 3" "2 3" "3"   "4"

## edited factor
recode(x, "1 2" = "1", "1 3" = "1", "2 3" = "2")
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 3 4
#> Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

P.S.: you should not edit your question in such a way that it invalidates (previously valid) answers.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73983546/17732851) to a recent question:

Under the hood, a factor array is an integer array with labels (levels). You can rename the labels alone without touching the underlying array.

```
d = data.frame(x = factor(c("1","1 2", "1 3", "2 3", "3", "4")))
levels(d$x)
[1] "1"   "1 2" "1 3" "2 3" "3"   "4" 

levels(d$x) <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
levels(d$x)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

d$x
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

If you have more levels, and don't want to risk a manual assignment, you can create a dictionary of replacement values

```
d = data.frame(x = factor(c("1","1 2", "1 3", "2 3", "3", "4")))
dict <- setNames(
    gsub(' .$', '', levels(d$x)), # remove spaces and any character after that
    levels(d$x)
)
dict
  1 1 2 1 3 2 3   3   4 
"1" "1" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

You can then use the dictionary to replace existing level labels with new ones

```
levels(d$x) <- dict[levels(d$x)]
d$x
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```